# No module named numpy but import works in command line

Tags: python, macos, numpy, matplotlib

I know this question has been asked dozens of times, but I still can't find my answer.

I was told that NumPy should be preinstalled on python 2.7 for OS X. To check, I was told to type "import numpy" in the command line in the terminal. No errors appear, suggesting that it's correctly installed. I then do "import matplotlib.pyplot as plot" and I'm told that the module doesn't exist.

NOW, moving out of the terminal to Eclipse, I type the same commands in my scripts, and neither of the packages work.

I'm using PyDev 2.8.2 for Eclipse 2.0.1 and Python 2.7. I also checked that I'm using Python 2.7 by typing "which python", and I can confirm this because the print command doesn't need (). BUT, I did have Python 3 installed at one point.

Thanks!

Comment: Based on my knowledge numpy, doesn't come in the default python installation. Try to do a pip install numpy

Comment: Your paths are messed up.  Make sure pydev is running the same version of python as at the command line and the location of `numpy` is in the path pydev uses.  There is a constant stream of questions on SO related to OSX being broken by design, added OSX tag so the right people see this.

Comment: @tcaswell: Thanks, I forgot that one. I'm gonna take a look at my paths and try to get to the bottom of it. I thought they were set correctly though.

Comment: Check the contents of `sys.version` on both interpreters. You probably have multiple versions installed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'd suggest:

1) Uninstall all other versions of python apart from the OS X system one. Make sure that none are left on your path with `which python` which should point to the OS X one.

2) Install [brew](http://brew.sh/), which is a package manager for OS X.

3) Use brew to install python - `brew install python`

4) Read up on brew's support of python [here](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python), it's pretty nice.

5) Use pip to install python packages, e.g `pip install numpy matplotlib`

6) If one of the packages needs a compiler you can install gcc with the brew formula `apple-gcc42` or clang with `llvm`

7) Perhaps try out the new community edition of [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/index.html)

Comment: I like these clear instructions, but I just have a few questions. 1. which version of python will I be installing? 2. To install brew I'm told to download the Command Line Tools for Xcode, but I can't find those anywhere. 3 Is pip something that I have to install?

Comment: 1. it will be 2.7 2. https://developer.apple.com/opensource/ on the right; apple want you to sign up to install a compiler on your system.. 3. brew's python will install pip for you, if you read the link I gave